# SQL request to find item in table by value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Its pretty simple question, I know, but I really stacked with a problem with it...

I have a table `customer_customer` and a column `code` in it. So I need to find all items with a specific `code` value. So I wrote that:

`SELECT * FROM customer_customer WHERE code LIKE "КL-12345"`

and got an error:

`column "КL-12345" does not exist`

Why `КL-12345` became a column if I specify it as value of `code` column? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM customer_customer WHERE code LIKE 'КL-12345'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM customer_customer WHERE code = 'КL-12345'
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't know about that...:/

Answer (score 4):

String literals must be enclosed in single quotes.
By enclosing it in double quotes, you specified a variable name.

Also, note that your where condition is the same as writing

```
where code = 'КL-12345'
```

`LIKE` is used for pattern matching. For instance you would match all codes that *contain* `'KL-12345'` like this

```
where code like '%KL-12345%'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining difference between `=` and `LIKE`. Actually, I tried both, but basic problem was in quotes as you see))

Comment: No problem. I'm not mad at you for choosing the other answer ;)